# May boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::send_to even fail?

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

Please consider following code snippet.

It first resolves address of remote host, then opens socket and sends some data to it. Note, it throws immediately when error occurs.

No concurrency involved. Message fits to 1K. Basically the only difference between this code snippet and "real" code is following: message may be sent in several seconds after endpoint was resolved and socket is opened.

```
using namespace boost::asio;
io_context io_context;

ip::udp::resolver resolver{io_context};
const auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(ip::udp::v4(), "host", "port");
if (endpoints.empty())
    throw std::runtime_error("No endpoints found");
const auto endpoint = endpoints->endpoint();

ip::udp::socket socket{io_context};
socket.open(ip::udp::v4());

const auto message = buffer("asdf"); // fits to 1K

// may the line below fail provided the code above is executed successfully?
socket.send_to(message, endpoint);
```

For me, provided the endpoint is valid and socket is opened successfully, it seems that call to `socket.send_to` should be always successful, even if remote host becomes unavailable (since UDP is used).

1. What exceptions should I expect in the last line?
2. Can I just assume that no errors will appear?
3. Should I expect *any* IO related error code there since we are doing IO anyway?

Comment: UPD protocol is "fire and forget" type. You do not receive confirmation that datagram has been received (like in TCP protocol). You can receive an error when for example your machine looses connection to the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIO implements this in terms of underlying operating system calls. On POSIX, that would be `sendto`. The possible error conditions are documented (see below).

However, first things first:

---

You could receive a segfault for addressing out of bounds into unknown address space. Depending on your platform it might manifest as `EFAULT` (`boost::asio::error::fault`).

```
const_buffer buffer{"asdf", 10};
```

The preferred spelling here is:

```
auto buffer = boost::asio::buffer("asdf"); // char[5] includes NUL
```

Which will send the `char[]` (including terminating NUL character) (see [overload](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload7.html)). If you don't want that, consider e.g. `boost::asio::buffer("asdf"sv)`, which uses a string view, without you having to call `strlen`.

> Note how you create naming conflicts where `buffer` hides `boost::asio::buffer` because of `using namespace`. You did the same with `io_context`. I'd advise against this level of flirting with danger in C++

### Other Notes

```
if (ec)
    throw std::system_error(ec);
```

Is not needed. If you don't supply `ec`, the exception `boost::system::system_error` (but from boost) will already be raised in the same fashion.

```
size_t sent = socket.send_to(
        ba::buffer("asdf"),
        endpoints->endpoint());
```

You use `endpoints->endpoint()` without validating the resolver results. Depending on situation zero or more resolutions might exist. You might be dereferencing an invalid iterator. This, again, can cause error conditions.

### Other Error Codes

You can get inspiration from the POSIX documentation: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html

The vast majority of the conditions are not applicable, partly due to it

- being datagram, not stream protocol
- the socket not being in non-blocking mode here (or that being abstracted away by ASIO)
- the socket being "known good" (assuming no concurrent code that you didn't show)

However a few remain:

- `EACCESS` can occur if you use a regular endpoint as if it were multicast
- `EDESTADDRREQ` if you pass an invalid endpoint (e.g. default constructed)
- `EINTR` unless you have signals ignored
- `ENOBUFS` (when the adapter is jammed - doesn't happen on linux where packets are just dropped)

Depending on the actual arguments in your real code:

- `EMSGSIZE` if your buffer exceeds the limit that can be sent atomically
- `EOPNOTSUPP` if you pass invalid flags

### SUMMARY

The real question is: do you anticipate any errors that you should deal with? If not simply accept the exceptions (I suggest *not* passing `error_code` parameters).

The only such condition I can think of is a failure to resolve the hostname. However, a quick test tells me the resultset will not be empty, but instead `resolve` throws `Host not found (authoritative)`.

So, just simplify:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef9a8627b09273a0)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace std::literals;
namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::udp;

int main() {
    ba::io_context io;
    udp::resolver resolver{io};
    auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(udp::v4(), "127.0.0.1", "6767");

    udp::socket socket{io};
    socket.open(udp::v4());

    return socket.send_to(ba::buffer("asdf"sv), endpoints->endpoint());
}
```

With

```
nc -u -l -p 6767 & sleep 1; ./a.out
```

Prints

```
asdf
```

Comment: Added [simplified demo live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef9a8627b09273a0)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, but I would like to clarify my question to highlight exactly what I am interested in.

Comment: So, I am wondering if call to send_to may fail if it's passed valid endpoint and small enough buffer.

Comment: @DmytroStarosud only when the network fails (or the hardware).

Comment: I think part of your answer (about posix errors codes) answers my question pretty well. Other parts may still be useful in general though. Could you please reformat your answer to highlight the part which is important for my question?

Comment: @DmytroStarosud Added introductory para. Cheers